# Create element with onInput event defined using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to create a DOM element using jQuery. I would like to create this DOM element with an 'on input' event defined.

This works:

```
var headerInput = $('<input/>', {
    'class': 'headerInput',
    type: 'text'
});

headerInput.on('input', function() {
    backgroundManager.get('activePlaylist').set('title', $(this).val());
});
```

This does not:

```
var headerInput = $('<input/>', {
    'class': 'headerInput',
    type: 'text',
    input: function(){
        backgroundManager.get('activePlaylist').set('title', $(this).val());
    }
});
```

I was wondering why? I thought these two syntaxes were identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says:

> As of jQuery 1.8, any jQuery instance method (a method of jQuery.fn) can be used as a property of the object passed to the second parameter.

but there is no such jQuery method `input`. Not for every event does an instance method exist.

You can use the `on` property as follows though:

```
var headerInput = $('<input/>', {
    'class': 'headerInput',
    type: 'text',
    on: {
        input: function(){
            backgroundManager.get('activePlaylist').set('title', $(this).val());
        }
    }
});
```

More info and examples can be found in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes).

Comment: Oh this is badass. I had no idea you could define on events like that. Thanks.